# How to detect if coaxial connection is plugged in?

Tags: circuit-design, detection

I'm designing the power stages at the moment and I'd love to disable unneeded circuitry when nothing is plugged in.

Right now there are two options to plug something in to get things going: USB and SPDIF (Coax). The USB is easy and I can just program a GPIO for that on the microcontroler. However what would the best way to detect SPDIF? The Jack does not offer a detection pin.

I'm thinking about getting a resistor and then a capacitor to average out the voltage on the SPDIF line and detecting if this line gets above 0.2V, indicating there is a signal. But I feel like this is such a hack-y way that it should be possible much easier

---

This is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

The output of the Comparator goes into the DAC chip which decodes the signal.

[LMV7219 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv7219.pdf)

Comment: Is your S/PDIF input or output?

Comment: If the SPDIF connection is a COAX connection then it will need to be terminated properly. When terminated properly the signal amplitude on the CAOX line halves. Perhaps you can detect that.

Comment: @PkP SPDIF input, so there will be a signal to detect

Comment: What SPDIF receiver are you using?

Comment: What is the "DAC chip"? Does it not have a status output of any sort?

Comment: You'll have to be able to receive S/PDIF data anyway, so you can detect it by trying to receive. If you get S/PDIF frames, you have a connection. If not, then not.

Comment: @DaveTweed A DAC "Digital to Analogue converter" - My device is a external audio device for CD players (SPDIF) or Computers (USB)

Comment: This is like pulling teeth -- **Which chip are you using?!?** Be specific!

Comment: Oh wait you actually wanted to know the exact chip? I'm using the ES9028PRO chip, there is no public datasheet on this one though and the NDA prevents me from sharing pages. It does have automute though, but I prefer to use connection detection as it will take about 75ms for the output voltage to settle and the chips to initialize, which means there is a very slight cut-off of the audio. If it ends up being too complicated to use a connection detection like this, I'll look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPDIF is capacitor-coupled AC, so you will not be able to average it to DC, since its average is zero.

LMV7219 draws low current, 1.1mA according to datasheet, does it really matter to turn it off to save power?

Anyway, the truth is elsewhere: most SPDIF sources will output continuous SPDIF with all samples set to zeros even while not playing, so if you want to auto-switch to the SPDIF input when there is signal, this will be quite difficult, you'd have to decode the SPDIF and check if there is actual audio in it or all zeros.

So your simple "Ac signal present" detection would only save 1mA when no source is plugged in, but not in the case a source is plugged in and outputs silence.

If you still want to detect it, I suggest feeding the output of LMV7219 to a  74HC4060. The SPDIF signal will act as clock, so the 4060's output will pulse if there is signal. It will pulse slow enough that you can connect it to a uC pin with a pin change interrupt on it, without getting interrupt overload.

But that doesn't turn off the comparator.

If you have an input selection knob, you can simply power up the comparator when the source is set to SPDIF...

Now, about your termination scheme, it needs some polishing up.

Most SPDIF sources have 75R output impedance, with a 100nF cap in series to AC-couple the signal. If this is the case, the termination resistor in the receiver will create a highpass, which will make the level threshold move around depending on the LF content of the signal. AC-coupling the termination on the receiver end with 100nF+75R will give much better signal integrity and less LF jitter.

EDIT for Dave: some old measurements.

No termination resistor (ouch!) :

[image: No termination resistor (ouch!)]

75R only: high pass filtering is visible since the source is AC coupled.

[image]

75R+10n: this re-aligns all transitions on the center and decreases data-dependent jitter in recovered clock.

[image]

Comment: Two things: First of all, S/PDIF is biphase-mark encoded, so there is no significant "LF content" to worry about. However, 10 uF as a coupling capacitor is excessively large. Second, presumably, the OP wants to disable the "DAC chip" (whatever that is) when the S/PDIF input isn't being used, not the comparator.

Comment: Hmm, disable the DAC, okay he should have explained it better... many audio DAC chips have an output pin for this purpose, usually it is called "zero detect" which can be used to tell when the data stream is all zeros. But that wouldn't of course disable the DAC. And there is no way to tell if the SPDIF has audio in it without decoding it... Regarding termination, see edit;)

Comment: Not just the DAC chip but the opamps, headphone amplifier and their power generators as well. Saves a nice 1-4W of power that would be totally wasted especially if someone would let the device run 24/7.

Not detecting if there is actually data in there is not needed, I just wanted to make sure there was something plugged in or not. The main usage of my device is audio playback over USB and SPDIF input is a additional feature so for most users it will work just fine. (They should just turn off the device when not in use anyways! haha). Could you tell me some more about the sn74hc4060 though?

Comment: Okay, if your DAC chip (which one btw?) has a Zero Detect pin, then you can use this to power up the rest of the audio processing circuitry. I suggest using the USB/SPDIF selection knob too. If it's set to USB, then power down when no USB stream is present. If it's SPDIF, then use the DAC's Zero Detect. Would this work?

Comment: Sounds like a decent solution which is much easier to implement. I'm using the ES9028PRO by the way as DAC

Answer (score 0):

Ac coupled charge pump on the output of the comparator?

SPDIF is biphase encoded so you should see a ~3MHz square wave there any time signal is present which a charge pump can trivially convert to DC to switch a transistor.